# splitting file into smaller files using by number of fields

Tags: python, unix, csv, sed, awk

I'm having a hard time breaking a large (50GB) csv file into smaller part. Each line has a few thousand fields. Some of the fields are strings in double quotes, others are integers, decimals and boolean.

I want to parse the file line by line and split by the number of fields in each row. The strings contain possibly several commas (such as ), as well as a number of empty fields.

> ,,1,30,50,"Sold by father,son and daughter for $4,000" , ,,,, 12,,,20.9,0,

I tried using

```
perl -pe'  s{("[^"]+")}{($x=$1)=~tr/,/|/;$x}ge  '  file >> file2
```

to change the commas inside the quotes to | but that didn't work.  I plan to use

```
awk -F"|" conditional statement appending to new k_fld_files file2
```

Is there an easier way to do this please? I'm looking at python, but I probably need a utility that will stream process the file, line by line.

Comment: So, is one column meant to be one file?

Comment: That's part of one line. There are several million lines.

Comment: better to re-export your file with field separator thats not included in your data. '|' char is usually safe, and visible, unlike the other favorite, the tab char. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Python - if you just want to parse CSV including embedded delimiters, and stream out with a new delimiter, then something such as:

```
import csv
import sys
with open('filename.csv') as fin:
    csvout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='|')
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        csvout.writerow(row)
```

Otherwise, it's not much more difficult to make this do all kinds of stuff.

Example of outputting to files per column (untested):

```
cols_to_output = {}
for row in csv.reader(fin):
    for colno, col in enumerate(row):
        output_to = cols_to_output.setdefault(colno, open('column_output.{}'.format(colno), 'wb')
        csv.writer(output_to).writerow(row)

for fileno in cols_to_output.itervalues():
    fileno.close()
```

Comment: use 'rb' mode otherwise multiline fields might not work on python 2.x

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` alternative.

Assuming the quoted strings are well formatted, i.e. always have starting and terminating quotes, and no quotes within other quotes, you could do the replacement you suggested by doing a `gsub` on every other field replacing `,` with `|`.

**With pipes**

Below is an example of how this might go when grabbing columns 3 through 6, 11 and 14-15 with `coreutils` `cut`:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '
  NF > 1 { 
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) { 
      gsub(",", "|", $i);
      $i = FS $i FS;       # reinsert the quotes
    }
    print
  }'\
| cut -d , -f 3-6,11,14-15 \
| awk -F'"' -v OFS='' -e '
    NF > 1 { 
      for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) { 
        gsub("\\|", ",", $i)
        $i = FS $i FS;       # reinsert the quotes
      }
      print
    }'
```

Note that there is an additional post-processing step that reverts the `|` to `,`.

**Entirely in awk**

Alternatively, you could do the whole thing in `awk` with some loss of generality with regards to range specification. Here we only grab columns 3 to 6:

*extract.awk*

```awk
BEGIN {
  OFS   = ""
  start = 3
  end   = 6
}
{
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
    gsub(",", "|", $i)
    $i = FS $i FS
  }
  split($0, record, ",")
  for(i=start; i<=end-1; i++) {
    gsub("\\|", ",", record[i])
    printf("%s,", record[i])
  }
  gsub("\\|", ",", record[end])
  printf("%s\n", record[end])
}
```